# NPOI check if a cell is erroneous (upgrading from 2.0 to 2.6)

Tags: npoi

I'm upgrading NPOI from 2.0 to 2.6, and i found a bit retrocompatibility problem (for my app).
In 2.0, this (simplified) code throws a generic exception (System.Exception) with the message "Unexpected celltype (ERROR)" when a formula evaluates an error (like #DIV0), and I manage the exception manually:

```
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new HSSFDataFormatter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string str = dataFormatter.FormatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
```

But now (2.6) it's recovering the text #DIV0, and I want to manage better the error on the formula and I think about use the property cell.ErrorCellValue, but it throws an exception when the formula is correctly evaluated, and I can't find how check it without catching exception. My draft code is this, but I don't like it:

```
if (cell.CellType == CellType.Error && cell.ErrorCellValue > 0)
{
    throw new Exception($"CellTypeError: {cell.ErrorCellValue}");
}
else if (cell.CellType == CellType.Formula)
{
    try
    {
        if (cell.ErrorCellValue > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"CellTypeError: {cell.ErrorCellValue}");
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        // Ignore the exception 
    }
}
string str = dataFormatter.FormatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
```

I think that it must be easier but I haven't found any clue anywhere.